# NullReferenceException in Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We had some code that would run through command line arguments and determine, among other things, whether to start a client or server (for a Unity Networking game). It had the code:

```
string[] commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
foreach (string arg in commandLineArgs)
{
    if (arg.StartsWith(PORT_COMMAND_LINE_PREFIX))
        var port = int.Parse(arg.Substring(PORT_COMMAND_LINE_PREFIX.Length).Trim());
        if (port >= 1024 && port < 49151)
        {
            ServerLoader.batchmodeServerPort = port;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This worked fine on standalone windows builds (where it was actually used) and on iOS (where I guess the arguments array was just empty). However, on Android we were getting a `NullReferenceException`, and we couldn't work out exactly where it was.

Comment: Any reason for the -1? ... some actual feedback would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding debug lines, we worked out that it was somehow thrown in the `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` call itself, rather than the array returned or anything in the array being null. Since it was not actually needed, we added an:

```
if (!Application.isMobilePlatform)
{
    string[] commandLineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
...
}
```

around the entire command line argument parsing code. I'm posting this as the answer to my question, as there doesn't seem to be any other explanation, or any other questions/answers about this on SO. Might be useful for others.

If anyone disagrees, and think they know what might have been happening, please do post alternative answers :)